# geoip_country_name_by_name(): Required database not available at C:/xampp/apache/bin/GeoIP.dat

Tags: php, geoip

do you know why it's happens?

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: geoip_country_name_by_name(): Required database not available at C:/xampp/apache/bin/GeoIP.dat.
```

i just installing [GeoIP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/geoip.installation.php)

thanks for advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download the GeoIP database and move it to the path referenced in your error. Download here: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/install/country/

Comment: download link is not working anymore it is taking to 404 page.

Answer (score 2):

If it can help: I had the same problem but only with the PHP CLI, I add to force the lib directory setting to fix this warning. This is quite weird because with Apache the path is not set and it works correctly:

**/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/geoip.ini**:

```
[geopip]
geoip.custom_directory = /usr/share/GeoIP
```

Comment: Same with PHP 7.1.

Comment: Inside php.ini or where?

Comment: I have added the file path. :)